# sidewaystable is positioned before normal table when using the apa6 document class

Tags: tables, rotating, apa6

I tried to use a normal table together with a sidewaystable in an apa6 class document. Following the APA guidelines, the table order should equal the order of appearance. However, if the normal table is positioned before the sidewaystable in the document, the table order is reversed in the output and the sidewaystable is placed before the normal table.

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating} % sidewaystable

\shorttitle{foo}

\begin{document}

Table \ref{tab:one} and \ref{tab:two}.

\begin{table}
\noindent
\captionbox{A small table.\label{tab:one}}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\toprule
a & b & c \\ \midrule
1 & 2 & 3\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\noindent
\captionbox{One large table.\label{tab:two}}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} \\ \midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

The text in the resulting document is `Table 2 and 1.` and not `Table 1 and 2.`.

I'm using the latest TeX Live packages.

Comment: apa class in man mode takes normal floats out of the main document flow (into a `.ttt` file) and re-inserts them at the end, and they get numbered when they are re-included at that point. sideways tables are apparently not supported and stay in the main document area as in normal latex.  You may be better using a normal table but just rotating the inner tabular with `\rotatebox`

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works nicely and does not require sidewaystables. If you add your solution as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I added an answer (so you can give me a point or two if you wish:-) But it looks to me like @Ulrike knows what she is talking about and you should accept hers.

Comment: Both approaches work fine. I just wanted to mark which solution I prefer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`apa6` uses the `endfloat` package to move the floats to the end of the document. But `endfloat` doesn't handle `sidewaystable` by default.

You can either use the option `floatsintext` to keep the table in the text:

```
\documentclass[man,floatsintext]{apa6}
```

Or you can use the commands of `endfloat` to add `sidewaystable` to the floats it manages:

```
\usepackage{rotating} % sidewaystable
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

`apa` class in man mode takes normal floats out of the main document flow (into a `.ttt` file) and re-inserts them at the end, and they get numbered when they are re-included at that point. sideways tables are apparently not supported and stay in the main document area as in normal latex. You may be better using a normal table but just rotating the inner tabular with `\rotatebox`