# apa6: Sidewaystable combined with threeparttable, endfloat problem

Tags: tables, apa6, endfloat

I am using the `apa6` class and want to place tables at the end of the manuscript. This works well with normal tables, and also with sidewystables. However, it does not work when a sidewaystable is combined with a threeparttable, as in the [example of the apa6 class](http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf).

Here's a MWE, where the table is positioned in the text, not at the end:

```
\documentclass[man,a4paper]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}    % for advanced math displays
\usepackage{rotating} % sidewaystable
% \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}


\title{Title}
\shorttitle{shorttitle}

\author{Batman}
\leftheader{Robin}
\affiliation{Batman Academy}
\date{February 20, 2013}


% Abstract: 250 words max, up to 5 keywords
\abstract{Abstract}
\keywords{}

\begin{document}    
\maketitle  %First line of text directly after \maketitle (no blank line)
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
      \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
      \midrule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text} \\
        Row 1 & 1 & 0.67 & 0.55 & 0.41 \\
        Row 2 & 2 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.39 \\
        Row 3 & 3 & 0.15 & 0.33 & 0.34 \\
        Row 4 & 4 & 1.00 & 0.76 & 0.54 \\
      \midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\section{Method}

\section{Results}

\section{Discussion}

\end{document}
```

To summarize, `table` + `threeparttable` works, `sidewaystable` alone works, but `sidewaystable` + `threeparttable` does not work.

The solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79840/sidewaystable-is-positioned-before-normal-table-when-using-the-apa6-document-cla), gives an error:

```
\usepackage{rotating} % sidewaystable
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}

Latex Error: ./Tabletest.tex:8 Undefined control sequence.
```

Comment: I get no error after adding the `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}` declaration. What version of `apa6` do you have?

Comment: I have Document Class: apa6 2013/06/26 v2.13 APA formatting (6th edition), and endfloat package v2.5 - should be the newest.

Comment: With `apa6.cls 2013/06/26 v2.13 APA formatting (6th edition)` and `endfloat.sty 2011/12/25 v2.5d LaTeX2e package puts figures and tables at end (jdm)` this works fine here, too. Make sure you have v2.5d of the `endfloat` package, previous ones had problems in conjunction with `apa6`.

Comment: Weird. I also have `apa6 2013/06/26 v2.13 APA formatting (6th edition)` and `endfloat 2011/12/25 v2.5d LaTeX2e package`, running an up-to-date MacTex TExLive system. Still, the table is printed on p. 4, before the Method header ...

Comment: And do you still get the LaTeX error when using `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor`? If yes I doubt that you are really using `endfloat` v2.5d since this command is defined there. (I know for sure since I'm the one who has introduced it in version 2.5.) Please take a look at the generated log file if you are really using this version.

Comment: Now it works - my fault. It was a combination of a local older endfloat.sty (which I removed, but then forgot to uncomment the \Declare... command). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP stated he has solved and it was due to typos