# Place sidewaystable at the end of document (below instead of above list of figures)

Tags: tables, positioning

I've seen a lot of questions concerning how to place a `sidewaystable` (I'm using the `rotating` package) floating in the document, but not one on how to place it at the end.

My documentclass is `\documentclass[Journal]{ascelike}` and I would like the `sidewaystable` to end up at the end of my document, below the list of figures. As it is now, the table ends up wherever I place it in the code.

How can I achieve the right position of my `sidewaystable`? It works perfectly fine with my standard tables.

Regards,
Kristin

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Sounds like this problem http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79843/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, it's a similar problem, thanks! Adding `floatsintext`to the document class did not work, but I tried the `\rotatebox` and it places the table at the end of the document. However, unlike `\sidewaystable`, `\rotatebox` does not turn the caption of the table.

Comment: Reread my answer. It doesn't mention `\rotatebox`.