# Table - APA6 class - rotating (with caption and table notes)

Tags: tables, rotating, apa6

I am trying to rotate this table with its caption and its table notes in APA6 class. I want to keep the default settings (table goes to the end of paper).

In my earlier approaches, I managed to turn the table (+ caption, + table notes) with landscape, but it breaks the settings and my table is shown in the text.

As I read here...
[sidewaystable is positioned before normal table when using the apa6 document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79840/sidewaystable-is-positioned-before-normal-table-when-using-the-apa6-document-class) ... I can use the rotate function. When I do this, I am only able to rotate the inner tabular{function}. In this case, the tabular itself is rotated and put to the end of document (as intended), but I cannot include the captions and the table notes (if I try to apply rotate on table overall, I get an error.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{Here}

\abstract{Here goes some text.}
\keywords{Some interesting stuff 1, and 2}

\maketitle

\title{Test}

Blabla, see table \ref{tab:Deskriptionen}.

\begin{table}
\caption{My table}
\vspace*{2em}
\label{tab:Deskriptionen}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr@{}} \toprule
Variable & M & SD & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\\ \midrule
1 Value $\bar{x}$ & $2.72$ & $.53$ & $1$ &&&&&&&&&&&& \\
13 Value  & $3.30$ & $1.17$ & $-.14$
& $-.14$ & $-.13$ & $-.06$ & $-,04$ & $-.63$\tabfnm{**} & $.78$\tabfnm{**} & $.81$\tabfnm{**} & $.72$\tabfnm{**} & $.47$\tabfnm{**} & $.70$\tabfnm{**} & $.59$\tabfnm{**} & $1$ \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
{\small
\textit{Anmerkung.} LE = Lernemotionen \tabfnt{*}\textit{p} < .05. \tabfnt{**}\textit{p} < .01.
}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{Here}

\abstract{Here goes some text.}
\keywords{Some interesting stuff 1, and 2}

\maketitle

\title{Test}

Blabla, see table \ref{tab:Deskriptionen}.

\begin{table}
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
\caption{My table}
\vspace*{2em}
\label{tab:Deskriptionen}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr@{}} \toprule
Variable & M & SD & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\\ \midrule
1 Value $\bar{x}$ & $2.72$ & $.53$ & $1$ &&&&&&&&&&&& \\
13 Value  & $3.30$ & $1.17$ & $-.14$
& $-.14$ & $-.13$ & $-.06$ & $-,04$ & $-.63$\tabfnm{**} & $.78$\tabfnm{**} & $.81$\tabfnm{**} & $.72$\tabfnm{**} & $.47$\tabfnm{**} & $.70$\tabfnm{**} & $.59$\tabfnm{**} & $1$ \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
{\small
\textit{Anmerkung.} LE = Lernemotionen \tabfnt{*}\textit{p} < .05. \tabfnt{**}\textit{p} < .01.
}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```